# Sent ETH to ETC address within Ledger Nano X - Blind Signing Error when trying to Transfer (have read old threads)

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-classic, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

I sent ETH to a ETC Leger Address. I have read the thread "Sent ETH to ETC address within Ledger Nano S. Confirmed on Etherscan, but not appearing in Wallet? [closed]" which has a good description.

I have already read Ledger's way of recoverying ETH sent to ETC adress here: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019363320-Eth-recovery-?docs=true

I have followed the instructions with both MyCrypto and MEW.

MEW is a little easier. I can locate the missing Eth I sent to my ETC address.

However - I cant resolve the Blind signing issue.

When I try and send the ETH out I get the error "Please enable Blind Signing or Contract data in the Etherum app Settings". I have checked Eth App, Etc App and Ledger's Eth Recovery App and all have Blind Signing enabled.

When I access MEW I need to use the Eth Recovery App. If I try and change to the Eth App just before sending Eth out (thinking this will fix the Blind Signing Issue) - I disconnect the Ledger and have to start again. Any suggestions?

The previous thread almost answered my problem, however I don't get what I need to do to resolve this part "I think this happens because you're trying to sign an ETH transaction with the ETC app open on your Ledger device. Like I mentioned, Ledger changed which derivation paths can be accessed, and trying to use the ETC derivation path with the ETH app open will likely result in an error."

Sorry this is a little muddled - have spent hours trying to set this fixed. The instructions seem simple yet that aren't giving me the results I need.

Thanks All for any pointers.

Comment: I understand you sent ether to an ETC address, so the ether is still in the Ethereum blockchain. In order to access those funds you need to tell Ledger to sign the transaction as it were an ETH address. I think you have to play with MEW or MyCrypto so they load the ETC address as an ETH address. I think you should only open the "Eth recovery app" for the recovery.

Comment: Thanks for response - I can only get into Mew to see the Eth in the ETC wallet if I have the ledger Eth Recovery App open on the ledger. If I change the ledger app to say ETC or ETH whilst in MEW the ledger connections drops.

Comment: You have to only use the Recovery app for the recovery, don't change the app until the recovery is complete. If you need the ETH address use it before.